# Maskilim and Jüdischkeit

Tags: history, historical-figures

I often hear that the maskilim of the 18th and 19th centuries were, without exception, secularists and religious reformers. Is this true or were some/most of them actually religious individuals who happened to have modern/radical ideas about secular culture, like some interpretations of מה”ר Hirsch ז”ל?

Comment: Define "maskilim".

Comment: Per Wikipedia: "is an identifier for individuals and ideas of the Haskalah movement, the European Jewish enlightenment between the 1770s and 1880s…" Many were grammarians and even some of the mainstream religious figures of the time, such as R' Wolf Heidenheim, were occasionally identified as such.

Comment: Well, if you define "Maskil" to include some individuals who were actually religious, then the answer is one way, and if you define "Maskil" to exclude all those individuals, then the answer is the other way. What I don't get is how playing out that [analytic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic%E2%80%93synthetic_distinction) tautology in q&a format is useful to anyone.

Comment: Notable religious maskilim include Maharats Hajes, Shir, Shadal, and R. D. Z. Hoffman.

Comment: The yeshiva in Volozhin was a hot-bed of maskilic sentiment, and many of the students went on to study in university. They were all religiously observant.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt To reiterate DoubleAA's points, and my point [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47971/maskilim-and-j%c3%bcdischkeit#comment233534_47972), you have to be more specific in what you define as maskil. If your a priori definition doesn't preclude the religious, you have answer. If it does, you also have an answer. Either way it is a meaningless question. || The way to make it a meaningful question, is to ask whether the Wissenschaft des Judentums approach; that which is what generally ties maskilim together in 19th century Europe, in contrary to religion.

Comment: [cont.] The answer to the above, would be that its focus was different from traditional religion; critical analysis, rather than faith based acceptance, and therefore its conclusions often differed, and thus most of its practitioners weren't religious, but, the two weren't fundamentally mutually exclusive. It is most similar to Modern and Orthodox. While Modern can include acceptance of the scientific method, and therefore it often yields results divergent from orthodoxy, the two are not by definition mutually exclusive, and we therefore find those who subscribe to both. [cont.]

Comment: [cont.] In the latter case, they constitute an entire religious movement, known as Modern Orthodoxy.

Comment: @mevaqesh, it looks like rather than refuting it, you are forming the framework for an answer.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I am not sure if you mean the refuting the dissertation, or your question. As it stands now, the question isn't really answerable, since it is like a single equation with two variables. I.e. it leaves maskil undefined. If you define maskil as a follower of the Wissenschaft des Judentums, then it seems answerable, as I believe I did in the comments. So, if you edit the question to make it answerable, I would be happy to post my comments as an answer. I could post them as it is, but I would have to assume a definition for maskil, which would make it a rather poor answer.

Comment: So, whatever you want; just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can read Rebbetzin Brurya Hutner-David's [thesis](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~spotter/david-chajes.pdf) on Maharatz Chajes. She calls him a Maskil but definitely religious.

Comment: Ooh. An anonymous downvote. Guess you don't like B.J.J.?

Comment: I didn't downvote but I didn't upvote either.....reason being that this doesn't really address the question fully (see also http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2187/5323)

Comment: @Shokhet But i wrote that her thesis states he was a Maskil and that he was religious. It wasn't a see here with no information.

Comment: More accurately, to summarize the whole dissertation, she paints a false dichotomy between maskil and religious traditionalist, and claims that Chajes was internally conflicted between the two.

Comment: @mevaqesh I am in no way agreeing with what you said, at all. It's almost as if you've never heard of the maskilim smoking on shabbos while learning a blatt of gemara. However I have heard that this was her own personal turmoil boiling to the surface. Apparently both her and her father took an extreme turn towards the right fringe after being held hostage. This work shows the depth of which she studied the authors works and then turns on him. The theory makes sense.

Comment: @user6591  Yes I am aware that there were those who were not religiously observant and also studied Torah. | My point, was that the term maskil was used to refer to those who belonged to a particular intellectual stream; the Wissenschaft des Judentums. Thus, the real answer to this question, is that by that definition, being religious and being a maskil are not mutually exclusive. | David's dissertation, like this question, never sets down a rigorous definition or set of criteria for "maskil", so her whole conversation lacks rigour, and rings hollow. [cont.]

Comment: [cont.] She does indeed draw a dichotomy between "maskil" and "religious", but only because she never provides a rigorous definition for the former, let alone demonstrate the usage of the term at the time, so that statements about it, would be anything other than meaningless tautologies.

Answer (score 0):

There are two who come to mind,Chaim Zelig Slonimski,and Mordechai Aron Guenzburg. They were both religious . There are more but dont remember their names off hand.

Side note: Moses Mendalshonn was orthodox but his children converted except for one I beileve.

Comment: I don't think the term orthodox was invented yet.  The question was about secularists and reformers.

Comment: FWIW one of the children of Rabbeinu Gershom converted too.