# What is a frum maskil?

Tags: history

What is a frum maskil?
I have seen people use the term to describe certain people from history. What exactly does this description mean? Was it used by any legitimate historians? And can some examples be given of people who fall under this category.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47971/maskilim-and-j%C3%BCdischkeit

Comment: http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~spotter/david-chajes.pdf

Comment: See if you can get hold of "My Uncle the Netziv" (or the Hebrew original Mekor Baruch) - he describes frum maskilim there (and how the Netziv got along well with them)

Comment: I don't suppose you're referring to the [chassidic intellectual](https://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9F_%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99:%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9C). Can you provide a little more context? Some examples?

Answer (score 1):

For many the fight against the Haskallah was not about Reform/Conservative approach to Halacha but rather against Western ideology. Specifically Western Philosophy applied to Judaism.

So a Frum Maskil would be someone who keeps (mostly) Torah and Mitzvot yet regardless studies Western Philosophy is involved in politics and mixes those with the Torah.

See מעין גנים by the מהרצ"א

Comment: "... _someone who keeps (mostly) Torah and Mitzvot yet regardless studies Western Philosophy is involved in politics and mixes those with the Torah._" That sounds a bit like a description of Modern Orthodox Jews (or, at least, their leaders and thinkers).

Comment: I am basing the view on the מהרצ"א